# TikZ: Node angles with offset

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, I can draw a node on the border of some other node, by specifying the angle, using the "name.angle" syntax. For example, the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
\node[draw,inner sep=1mm,fill=red] (B) at (A.30) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces this picture, where the red node is 30° at the intersection of A's border and a line, heading towards 30°, starting at the center of A, i.e. at 2 o'clock:

[image: the picture. a red square at 2 o'clock around a node]

Is there a way I can get a similar result, but where the red square is not on the border, but some distance away from it?

Comment: `\path (A) + (30:1) node {red square};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By use of the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,circle] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
        \node[draw,inner sep=1mm,fill=red] (B) at ($(A.30)+(30:5mm)$) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Is the `30` needed in `(A.30)`?

Comment: No, just replace `5mm` by a larger amount at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You mean like with `yshift` and `xshift`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,circle] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
        \node[draw,inner sep=1mm,fill=red,yshift=5pt,xshift=5pt] (B) at (A.30) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this approach easily shifts the dot off the 30° axis. You would have to carefully compute the shifting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pos` key to put the node at some factor times the radius away from the center. In this example the center of the square is at twice the radius (`pos=2`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,circle] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
 \path (A.center) -- node[draw,inner sep=1mm,fill=red,pos=2] (B) {} (A.30);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `label` is already a `node`, then why not use `labels` to draw these nodes?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle, 
    label={[draw, inner sep=1mm, fill=red, shift={(30:3mm)}, anchor=center]30:}, 
    label={[draw, circle, inner sep=1mm, fill=blue, shift={(120:5mm)}, anchor=center]120:}, 
    ] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update:*

From OPs comment I understand he/she wants to place a new node relative to the previous one.

Two options:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle, 
    ] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
%This line aligns its `west` anchor with a point `(30:1cm)` far from circle center
\path (A.center) --++(30:1cm) node[right,draw] {This is a new line};
%This line aligns its `north west` anchor with a point `(0:5mm)` far from circle border
\node[below right, draw] at ([xshift={5mm}]A.-45) {This is a another line};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because I might want to start a line at that point.

Comment: @JoJoModding I've updated the answer with what I assume you wants. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (A) at (0,0) {foo bar};
\draw (A) +(30:2 cm) node[draw,inner sep=1mm,fill=red] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red square 2cm away from circle node]